# Use of Shell object in Gjs

Tags: gnome-shell

I am writing a gtk+ app using Gjs ( Gnome JavaScript bindings )
As there are no documents available i am reading the sources of gnome-shell JavaScript's .
In my app i need to get access to `global.userdatadir` .

I am trying to add the Shell object to my script :

```
const Shell = imports.gi.Shell;
```

and run it with `#gjs myscript.js`
but when i do this it throws me an error saying :

```
JS ERROR: !!!   Exception was: Error: Requiring Shell, version none: Typelib file for namespace 'Shell' (any version) not found
    JS ERROR: !!!     lineNumber = '0'
    JS ERROR: !!!     fileName = '"gjs_throw"'
    JS ERROR: !!!     stack = '"("Requiring Shell, version none: Typelib file for namespace 'Shell' (any version) not found")@gjs_throw:0
@manager.js:5
"'
    JS ERROR: !!!     message = '"Requiring Shell, version none: Typelib file for namespace 'Shell' (any version) not found"'
Error: Requiring Shell, version none: Typelib file for namespace 'Shell' (any version) not found
```

I cant understand what's wrong with it , it is exactly as in Gnome-shell source files.
Other objects are fine using `imports.gi.Gio` , `imports.gi.GLib` , works OK .

Working on Ubuntu 11.10 x64

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't run gnome-shell extensions via gjs, they have to be loaded by gnome-shell itself. For development, this usually means putting them in `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/YOUR-EXTENSION-ID` and restarting the shell.

Answer (score 3):

**Call `org.gnome.Shell.Eval` via dbus.**

As gfxmonk points out, the JavaScript code should be run by the shell itself. If you’re *not* writing an extension, the way to do that is via dbus, for instance using systemd’s `busctl`. (I’m sure it’s also possible via `dbus-send`, I just prefer `busctl`’s syntax. And it has tab completion!)

For example, this logs all window titles:

```
busctl --user call org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell Eval s '
    for (const actor of global.get_window_actors()) {
        const window = actor.get_meta_window(),
              title = window.get_title();
        log(title);
    }
'
```

You can see the log messages with `journalctl /usr/bin/gnome-shell 'GLIB_DOMAIN=GNOME Shell'`. (You probably want to add `-b` too to only see messages from the current boot, or `--since '5 minutes ago'`, … – see **journalctl**(1) for more options.)

Alternatively, [this GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/buzztaiki/1492431) describes how to get at the `Shell` module in `gjs` (add `/usr/lib/gnome-shell` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and to `GIRepository.Repository`’s search path), but I haven’t managed to get access to a `global` object using that.

---

Note that since Gnome 41, [calling Eval is restricted](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/commit/7298ee23e91b756c7009b4d7687dfd8673856f8b), so you’ll need to run `global.context.unsafe_mode = true` in Looking Glass (<kbd>Alt+F2 lg</kbd>) first.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ apt-file search -x "Shell.*typelib"
gnome-shell: /usr/lib/gnome-shell/Shell-0.1.typelib
gnome-shell: /usr/lib/gnome-shell/ShellJS-0.1.typelib
gnome-shell: /usr/lib/gnome-shell/ShellMenu-0.1.typelib

$ sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```